# add and subtract the total when clone/remove the rows from the table using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a dynamic table with rows of data including options of add and remove row of a table . i have to calculate of the each row total and final total of all row total . when i add a row , total is summing up but i m not getting how do i subtract the total  when i remove the row .

My table view

```
<table class="" id="table-data">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th> Qty</th>
      <th>days</th>
      <th>rate</th>
      <th>rowtotal</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="qty[]" placeholder="Qty" class="form-control Qty">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="days[]" placeholder="Days" class="form-control Days">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="rate[]" placeholder="Rate" class="form-control rate">
      </td>

      <td>
        <input type="text" autocomplete="off" readonly="" name="row_total[]" id="row_total0" placeholder="Row    Total" class="form-control rowTotal">
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm" role="group" aria-label="">
          <button type="button" class="addline btn btn-sm btn-primary">+</button>
          <button type="button" class="delete btn btn-sm btn-danger">-</button>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<input type="text" readonly="" autocomplete="off" name="total_net" class="form-control" value="Total" id="TotalNet">
```

and below is the jquery to calculate the total :

```
var calcObject = {
  run: function () {

    var id = '';
    var sum =bundleSum=qtyVal=daysVal=rateVal=rowtotal =calcVat=daysvalue=ratevalue=FinalRow=0;
     //iterate through each textboxes and add the values

    $(".Qty").each(function () {
      //add only if the value is number
      if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
        qtyVal =  parseFloat(this.value);
      }
        daysVal =  $(this).closest('tr').find("td:eq(1) input[type='text']").val();
        if (!isNaN(daysVal)) {
          daysvalue = parseFloat(daysVal);
        }
        rateVal =  $(this).closest('tr').find("td:eq(2) input[type='text']").val();
        if (!isNaN(rateVal)) {
          ratevalue = parseFloat(rateVal);
        }

        rowtotal = Math.round(parseFloat(qtyVal)*parseFloat(daysvalue)*parseFloat(ratevalue));
        if (!isNaN(rowtotal)) {
          FinalRow = parseFloat(rowtotal);
        }
        id =  $(this).closest('tr').find("td:eq(3) input[type='text']").attr('id');
        $('#'+id).val(parseFloat(FinalRow).toFixed(2));

    });

    $(".rowTotal").each(function () {
      //add only if the value is number
      if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
        sum +=  parseFloat(this.value);
      }
    });
    $('#TotalNet').val(parseFloat(sum).toFixed(2));
    var net = $('#TotalNet').val();
  }

};
```

[demo js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fyhsz9ra/1236/)

any suggestions please ? Thank you

Comment: How do you "remove" the row?  It looks like your values are calculated on the fly, so `$(".rowTotal")` will only return the rows that exist.  If you are "removing" by simply "hiding" then use something like `$(".rowTotal:visible")` or add a class when you hide and use `$(".rowTotal:not(.myhiddenclass)")`

Comment: how about insert `calcObject.run();` just before your `return false;` in the delete click function . aka like this http://jsfiddle.net/51479bbh/

Comment: You really should create an [mcve] - which would show your remove button and that all you need is `calcObject.run()` when you remove the lines: updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fyhsz9ra/1237/  (edit: What @CarstenLøvboAndersen said)

Comment: Thank you so much @CarstenLøvboAndersen & freedomn-m